# Https wcf webservice Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="serviceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="webHttp">
  <webHttp />
 </behavior>
 <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
 <webHttp />
 </behavior></endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
  <services>
  <service name="Implementation.Service" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"   contract="Contract.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"    bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"></endpoint>
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="CodeItSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00">
   <security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType ="Basic"  realm =" "/>
 <message clientCredentialType= "username" algorithm ="default">
  </security>
 </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
  <client>
 <endpoint address="https://******.****-***/*****_*****?SOAP"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CodeItSoap"
 contract="Service.CodeItSoap" name="CodeItSoap" />
</client>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

This is just a sample of my web.config file. When I run the service in the local host it runs fine and with the help of wcf test client I am getting the required output.
But when I put the `dlls` & `web.config` in the server where I have to host the service it's throwing an error
 `"Could not find a base address that matches scheme HTTP for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]"`

Could any one tell me what the reason for the above error is?
General Flow of my web service
 Application -> Server hosting(calc.svc) -> https://******.****-***/*****_*****?SOAP(authenticated)
when i add the service reference app.config got generated and by default basichttpbinding got added to app.config file.
As per my understanding web.config file is used to host the service in iis & i think my web.config is wrong.
In the client end point what should be the end point to calc.svc or https://***?soap?
Is the basichttpbinding ok for the https://prd36/calc.svc url?
do i need to specify one more binding for the application too?
Please help me understand i am heavily confused as the web.config which i have edited is a existing one which is still running the old service reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/> 
 <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Contract.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint> 
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

above changes i did and the service url is running in web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use **http://**  instead of **https://** in your endpoint address.
OR
User **BasicHttpsBinding** instead of **BasicHttpBinding** in your endpoint.

follow [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/10/10/whats-new-in-wcf-45-basichttpsbinding/) if the problem still exist.